# Quote: nearly impossible for artists to critique themselves well?

Tags: quotes

In the recently-released movie, Birdman, Michael Keaton's character witters a seemingly famous quote to Edward Norton's character about artists critiquing themselves and how it is nearly impossible to do well.

What is that quote?

Or, what is a reputable quote that represents the notion that constructively self-criticizing one's music or art is very challenging?

Comment: Shaw, asked what his *Heartbreak House* meant, answered  'How should *I* know? I am only the author.'

Comment: From [The Later Diaries of Ned Rorem: 1961-1972](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pmz5XVnBRYMC&pg=PT10&lpg=PT10&dq=%22assess+his+own+work%22+artist&source=bl&ots=EYxHmt2W9l&sig=7-DKeiviVROQ0FZaCiCOuN3-1so&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z75wVM6bGdHraoeMgdAC&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22assess%20his%20own%20work%22%20artist&f=false) *An artist able to assess his own work is already dead.*

Comment: The only relevant quote I can find in the [recently-published script](http://d97a3ad6c1b09e180027-5c35be6f174b10f62347680d094e609a.r46.cf2.rackcdn.com/film_scripts/FSP3823_BiRDMAN_MINI_SCRIPT_BOOK_C5.pdf) (PDF) is said by Mike [Edward Norton], quoting Flaubert: "A man becomes a critic when he can not be an artist, in the same way that a man becomes an informer when he cannot be a soldier."

Answer (score 1):

Just as with self-policing, self-insurance, self-regulation, and self-(fill in the blank),

> Self-criticizing/criticism is no criticizing/criticism at all.